# sort random array using only one loop without sort function

Tags: javascript

can i sort random array using only **one loop** without using sort function ??? but can i do the same using one for loop ? how can i do that ?
here i'm use nested loop

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function sortarr(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
          var temp = arr[i];
          arr[i] = arr[j];
          arr[j] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }
  console.log(sortarr([10, 18, 4, 5, 9, 6, 16, 12]));
});
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use sort?

Comment: `console.log(sortarr([10,18,4,5,9,6,16,12]));});` what's going on with this line here?

Comment: I mean, I guess technically, you can keep resetting your array counter back to the beginning until the array is sorted, rather than using nested loops.. but the big O time complexity would be the same. What is your use-case?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by `one loop`. Any comparison sort's time complexity is bounded from below by `n * lg n` therefore you can't sort it by just `one loop`, that would be sorting in `n` time complexity.

Comment: @MatusDubrava It is possible to use one loop, but not one pass through the elements, so yes, time complexity will remain the same - see my above comment

Comment: Check out this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/

Comment: You can also do it with 0 loops, using only recursion via something like a merge sort

Comment: @mhodges Yes i know, that is why I said it depends on the definition of `one loop` but I guess `one pass trough array` would be a better formulation here as you have noted.

Comment: @MatusDubrava Yeah, one can assume - hard to tell exactly what OP truly wants, though.

Comment: what is the big o of sort ?

Comment: @ammarammary Just about every built-in sort function to any language uses a quick sort or merge sort (or something similar), which is `O(n*log(n))`. The exact implementation in JavaScript is browser-dependent, as it is not defined in the spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested, this is how you might implement your own quicksort.

But note that using default `js` sort would be much faster than any implementation that you can do yourself (most probably) as that sort is optimized to run as fast as possible. This is just an implementation of a generic textbook `quicksort`.

```js
const quicksort = arr => {

  const _partition = (arr, begin, end) => {
    let pivot = begin;
    for (let i = begin; i <= end; i++) {
      if (arr[i] < arr[begin]) {
        pivot++;
        [arr[pivot], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[pivot]];
      }
    }
    [arr[begin], arr[pivot]] = [arr[pivot], arr[begin]];
    return pivot;
  }

  const _quicksort = (arr, begin, end) => {
    if (begin < end) {
      const pivot = _partition(arr, begin, end);
      _quicksort(arr, begin, pivot - 1);
      _quicksort(arr, pivot + 1, end);
    }
  }

  _quicksort(arr, 0, arr.length);
}

const arr = [10, 18, 4, 5, 9, 6, 16, 12];
quicksort(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

And you can make it a little bit faster (in some cases) by randomizing the `pivot` selection like this.

```js
const quicksort = arr => {

  const _partition = (arr, begin, end) => {
    let pivot = begin;
    for (let i = begin; i <= end; i++) {
      if (arr[i] < arr[begin]) {
        pivot++;
        [arr[pivot], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[pivot]];
      }
    }
    [arr[begin], arr[pivot]] = [arr[pivot], arr[begin]];
    return pivot;
  }

  const _randomizedPartition = (arr, begin, end) => {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (end-begin)) + begin;
    [arr[begin], arr[index]] = [arr[index], arr[begin]];
    return _partition(arr, begin, end);
  }

  const _quicksort = (arr, begin, end) => {
    if (begin < end) {
      const pivot = _randomizedPartition(arr, begin, end);
      _quicksort(arr, begin, pivot - 1);
      _quicksort(arr, pivot + 1, end);
    }
  }

  _quicksort(arr, 0, arr.length);
}

const arr = [10, 18, 4, 5, 9, 6, 16, 12];
quicksort(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do mergesort with one loop only:

```
function mergeSort(arr) {
  if(arr.length < 2) return arr

  const a = mergeSort(arr.slice(0, arr.length / 2)),
             b = mergeSort(arr.slice(arr.length / 2));

 const result = [];

  while(a.length && b.length)
    result.push((a[0] > b[0] ? a : b).shift());

  return result.concat(a, b);
}
```

But as outlined in the comments above, this won't be faster than an approach with multiple loops, probably slower.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a chart showing various sorting algorithms and their complexities:

[image]

A single pass through a loop without recursion or nesting is O(n), so no, not in the worst case.  There are other techniques for sorting that can be incorporated to sort an array using a single loop as Jonas W. shows, but their time complexity isn't necessarily as good as good old `.sort()` which is Quicksort.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort a random array using only one loop without using sort function

```
a = [10, 18, 4, 5, 9, 6, 16, 12];
for(i=0; i< a.length-1;(a[i]>a[i+1]) ? ((a[i]=a[i]^a[i+1]) && (a[i+1]=a[i]^a[i+1]) && (a[i]=a[i]^a[i+1]) && (i=0)): i++) {}
console.log(a); // 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 16, 18
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.